# Trivial JQuery $.ajax Json Post to ASP.NET MVC2 controller: Cannot get Controller to see JSON (or anything)

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2, post

I went through dozens of answers to figure out the trick to posting data from $.ajax to a parameter in MVC 2's Controller.  Here's as far as I got:

BTW this works if you use a GET, but fails as a POST.  How would I fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Get",
        data: {value:'9/14/2010 12:00:00 AM'},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.value);
        }
    });
});
```

And this is my MVC 2 Controller:

```
public class strange
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult Get(strange o)
{   
    var b = new strange { value = "return" };
    return Json(b, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Upon POST, o's "value" is null.  Changing POST to GET, o's "value" is "9/14/2010 12:00:00 AM".

How do I get the POST to work with $.ajax?

Did anyone ever post a guide to getting JSON working with MVC2 data validation when returning JSON from the client?  I know they had that in their MVC 2 futures a while ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass JSON to the controller, and it's looking for a `strange` object, all you're currently passing is a string called `value`, instead your `data` should look like this:

```
{ strange: { value:'9/14/2010 12:00:00 AM'} }
```

Notice how `strange` is not an object with the `value` property the server is looking for.  But, it'll expect this as a string, so just use `JSON.stringify()` (use [JSON2](http://www.json.org/js.html) if needed for other browsers, e.g. < IE8):

```
data: JSON.stringify({ strange: { value:'9/14/2010 12:00:00 AM'} }),
```

Comment: When I changed the data to { strange: { value: '9/14/2010 12:00:00 AM' } }, null still comes in under value.  I will look in to the output of stringify to see what happens there.

Comment: This is what was posted: strange%5Bvalue%5D=9%2F14%2F2010+12%3A00%3A00+AM but it doesn't show up on the server under anything I can see (value remains null)

Comment: @DrZim - Looks like you're not using `JSON.stringify()` like I have above ;)

Comment: Adding Phil Haack's MVC2 Futures And using JSON.stringify() solved it.  Apparently, there's a huge difference between my JSON and JSON.stringify()'s version.  Thanks a lot for helping out.

Answer (score 2):

The data which you send to the ASP.NET MVC Controller should **not be JSON encoded**. So you should just remove the line

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

from the `$.ajax` request and your program will work.

Comment: @Dr. Zim: with `JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); MyData data = serializer.Deserialize<MyData> (encodedInput);`. Then you can use `$.ajax` with `data: {encodedInput: JSON.stringify(myData)}` and everything will work OK. So you can implement different scenarios in MVC2 RTM.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion.  Very nice alternative.  I will try that next.